# Can't get function to work right. Extra numbers that shouldn't be displayed

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and programming in general so this is all difficult for me but I am really trying to learn. I can't get the letterGrade function to display correctly.  I gives me the letter grade like it should but also adds a bunch of numbers after the letter grade.  Could anyone please let me know what is going on and what I am doing wrong?  Also I am supposed to use a function to find the average but I can only make it work by defining a variable sAverage in my "for" loop to display the array like a table. I had created a function for that as well but it didn't give me the right answer.  Here is my code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int letterGrade(int average)
{
    if (average > 89)
        cout << "A";
    else if (average > 79 && average < 90)
        cout << "B";
    else if (average > 69 && average < 80)
        cout << "C";
    else if (average > 59 && average < 70)
        cout << "D";
    else if (average >= 0 && average < 60)
        cout << "F";
}

void getInfo()
{
    const int info = 2;
    string last[info];
    string first[info];
    int ID[info];
    int score1[info];
    int score2[info];
    int score3[info];

    for (int count = 0; count < info; count++)
    {
         cout << "last name\n";
         cin >> last[count];
         cout << "first name\n";
         cin >> first[count];
         cout << "enter ID\n";
         cin >> ID[count];
         cout << "enter test 1\n";
         cin >> score1[count];
         cout << "enter test 2\n";
         cin >> score2[count];
         cout << "enter test 3\n";
         cin >> score3[count];
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Last Name\tFirst Name\tID\tTest 1\tTest 2\tTest 3\tAverage\t Grade\n";
    cout <<    "__________________________________________________________________\n";
    for (int count = 0; count < info; count++)
    {
        int sAverage = ((score1[count]+score2[count]+score3[count])/3);

        cout << setw(10) << last[count] 
             << setw(10) << first[count] 
             << setw(10) << ID[count] 
             << setw(10) << score1[count]
             << setw(10) << score2[count] 
             << setw(10) << score3[count] 
             << setw(10) << sAverage 
             << setw(10) << letterGrade(sAverage);
        cout << endl;
    }
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Enter Student Info\n";
    getInfo();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The function I had to find the average was:

```
int getAverage(score1, score2, score3)
{
    int average;
    average = ((score1 + score2 + score3) / 3);
    return average;
}
```

I called it like this

```
cout << getAverage(score1[info],score2[info],score3[info])
```

but it only came back with a high number in the hundreds but what I need is a function do average the scores in the array from the input.

Thanks in advance and again I am new to all this.

Comment: When posting code here, I suggest that you consolidate multiple blank lines so we don't have to page down so much (and I think code is much more readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mis-read your output? The `getAverage` function should work correctly even though you didn't specify types for the parameters (they default to `int`, then).

It looks like your problem is a different one: your function `letterGrade` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns random junk. Your compiler should actually warn you about that. This junk is interpreted as a number (since you said the function is returning `int`) and formatted that way.

What you probably want is something like:

```
string letterGrade(int average)
{
    if (average > 89)
        return "A";
    else if (average > 79 && average < 90)
        return "B";
    else if (average > 69 && average < 80)
        return "C";
    else if (average > 59 && average < 70)
        return "D";
    else if (average >= 0 && average < 60)
        return "F";
    else
        return "-"; // negative value was passed!
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much.  Thanks to everyone who responded!  I have it working now.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the function:

```
cout << getAverage(score1[info],score2[info],score3[info])
```

where info is equal to 2, you're accessing memory out of bounds of the array. You're length of an array is 2, so the only valid indices are 0,1 - not 2.

Moreover, in the definition of function:

```
int getAverage(score1, score2, score3)
{
    int average;
    average = ((score1 + score2 + score3) / 3);
    return average;
}
```

You didn't specify the types of scoreX variables, and the the implicit int rule is not valid in C++.

EDIT:
Another thing: when you're calculating the average, you have to remember that dividing an integer by an integer always gives an integer, so if you want to have more precise answer, e.g. for 2.66 2 3 3, you have to use a float.

Comment: Nice spot, I've missed that he used `info` instead of `count` when getting the array values.

Comment: I fixed that and it's working now thanks!  For this we aren't using decimals that's why I used int.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You use `<<` within a function without flushing `cout`. In fact, you say in the `letterGrade` prototype that you return an `int` but you don't, so when you call something like `cout << letterGrade(...)`, it prints a random number

The protoype of `letterGrade` should rather be :

```
string letterGrade(int average)
```

and you must return your letter (using for example `return "F";` instead of `cout << "F"`).

It is often bad idea to print on the standard output without `endl` nor `cout.fflush()`.